# How to add converter APPLICATION_PDF to the client in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using the standard SpringDecoder, but HttpMessageConverters doesn't have a converter that supports MediaType APPLICATION_PDF

```
@Bean
    fun decoder(messageConverters: ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters>) = SpringDecoder(messageConverters)
```

```
@PostMapping("/download/receipt")
    fun downloadReceipt(@PathVariable id: Long, @PathVariable receiptId: Long): ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource>
```

```
"Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource>] and content type [application/pdf]"
```

Please tell me how to fix this problem

Add new converters to HttpMessageConverters failed

Answer (score 0):

Configure your WebMvcConfigurer as follows:

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {

    override fun configureMessageConverters(converters: MutableList<HttpMessageConverter<*>>) {
        converters.add(ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter())
        converters.add(ResourceHttpMessageConverter())
    }
}
```

Then try this code to return response:

```
val pdfContent: ByteArray = ...
val resource = ByteArrayResource(pdfContent)
val responseEntity: ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> = ResponseEntity.ok()
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
    .body(resource)
```